# getAttribute('nonce') works in Firefox, but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, security, nonce

Given I am loading a script like this:

```
<script nonce="35609alksdgx30q" src="example.com/main.js"></script>
```

And inside `main.js` I need to grab the nonce on the script tag:

```
const currentScriptElement = document.currentScript
const nonce = currentScriptElement.getAttribute('nonce')
```

If `console.log(nonce)`, I get two different values:

- In Firefox (latest), I get: `35609alksdgx30q` as expected.
- In Chrome (latest), I get: `""` (blank string) which I don't expect.

If I get the nonce using the experimental nonce property ([HTMLElement.nonce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/nonce)), I get the following values:

- In Firefox (latest), I get: `null` as expected (because nonce property is not supported by Firefox)
- In Chrome (latest), I get: `35609alksdgx30q` as expected.

So to reliably get the nonce, I have to do something like this:

```
const nonce = currentScript.nonce || currentScript.getAttribute('nonce') || false
```

My question is, **why doesn't `getAttribute('nonce')` consistently return the nonce value?** I suspect this is a security thing, but then why doesn't Firefox also return an empty string when using `getAttribute('nonce')`?

---

Yes, I know technically `nonce` is used for inline scripts, and yes this script is cleared by the site's CSP policy. I have  to grab `nonce` this way due to how some things were implemented xD

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is trying to stop people from using CSS attribute selectors to exfiltrate nonces, and Firefox is lagging behind on following their lead.

(You'll also notice if you open up the console that Chrome has replaced the full nonce value in the DOM with an empty `nonce` attribute).

See: https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5685968463986688, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=680419